# Building Silverlight Games for Web and Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to build a game for windows phone 7 using Silverlight (it's not that complicated to require XNA).  Can I deploy the application as both Silverlight 4 web site and Silverlight WP7 game?  Is that a large effort?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Theorically you can develop common application for both platforms even there are some third party common libraries for both platforms Like Facebook v5 API.

You should only make few tweaks/changes in your applications so that they can run well on Windows Phone and Silverlight On Browser.

You can have the example of those applications from
[create.msdn.com](http://create.msdn.com).

From here you can see variety of sample applications having some common logic and some layer of platform specific logic in various example.

Windows Phone provides some additional APIs to silverlight.

I am already creatinga  common universal app for both platforms . This simply required making few changes in UI part of Coding in you applications.Remaining parts can be reused.

I hope this helps upto some extent

Answer (score 2):

in theory it could be possible but I think the SL for windows phone and SL web are not 100% the same, in Windows Phone SL doesn't run in a browser at all.

If you engineer your application properly and put all logic to some business logic libraries, eventually you will have to support two different UIs one for web and one for Windows Phone 7.

Both SL implementations use XAML but I don't think it will be fully portable out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm sure you've guessed, the answer is **IT DEPENDS**!

From a technical standpoint there isn't a lot that you can do in WP7 that you can't do in SL4. These are mostly platform (phone) specific things any you wouldn't be trying to do them in SL anyway.

Here are some areas where you may have possible issues though:

- Integrating with backend systems (if you centrally record high score tables etc.) - Likely only an issue if not doing this with straight HTTP(s) requests or you wanted to intgrate multiple concurrent players on different screens.
- Your game may require a different UI for the different size/ratio/dimension screens.
- Your game may require different input mechanisms for the different platforms